# Toy example of an Ansible dynamic inventory script?

Tags: ansible

In an attempt to debug my 'proper' script - I've resorted to trying a toy example - and that isn't working either.

```
 echo {\"admin\": \"foo\", \"datacenter\": \"bar\"}
```

Running it directly behaves as expected:

```
%: ./test_inv --host blah
{"admin": "foo", "datacenter": "bar"}
```

but:

```
%: ansible blah -i test_inv
ERROR: The file test_inv is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with `chmod -x test_inv`.
```

(I'm assuming that I don't need to support --list for this toy test as I'm never invoking it in that way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm assuming that I don't need to support --list for this toy test as I'm never invoking it in that way

This is your problem.  You know what they say about assumptions, right?  Here's a quick test for you to try:

Create an inventory file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Called as: $*" >> log

if [ "$1" == "--list" ] ; then
  echo '{ "localhost" : [ "localhost" ] }'
else
  echo '{ "some_variable": "some value" }'
fi
```

Now run ansible like this:

```
$ ansible -i ./hosts -m setup localhost
```

It should run without error and display all the facts for localhost. Once that's done:

```
$ cat log
Called as: --list
Called as: --host localhost
```

So ansible is invoking the executable hosts file twice, once with the `--list` parameter and once with the `--host <hostname>`. (If you invoked ansible with a list of hosts or a group that contained multiple hosts then the script would be called with the `--host` parameter once for each host).

Since your inventory script didn't return a list of valid hosts when ansible ran it with the `--list` parameter it threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The question originally had incorrect quoting hence this initial answer. The problem still remained once the quoting was fixed.

When you look at your output, you will see the quotes got stripped from your `echo`. I think Ansible just complains in its very spacial way about invalid JSON data. Try to escape the quotes like so:

```
echo {\"admin\": \"Bob Smith\", \"datacenter\": 1}
```

Edit: Basically what you have edited into your question. Does it work that way?

Comment: Thanks. Someone else pointed out the quoting mistake and I updated the question - but no - it didn't help.